# Optimizing load time while supporting JavaScript disabled browsers

Tags: performance, javascript

I have a large background image that is a major part of my design, but is not essential, that I am planning to load via JavaScript after the rest of my page has loaded. I would like my users to be able to interact with my more important content while this large file loads.

I would like to support JavaScript disabled users as much as possible, while maintaining optimal load times for everyone else. Is there a way to force an element to load last when javascript is disabled? If not, what's your opinion - is it better to fully support non-javascript users or optimize my site for everyone else?

Comment: Go for optimisation for everyone else. Non-javascript users are a very small percentage of web users.

Comment: Image loading will not freeze anything on the page and is going simultaneously with other resources.

Comment: @claustrofob My concern here is that my more essential images will have to compete with this larger, less essential image. I know it's a case specific judgement call unless there's a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include a style block at the very bottom of your page (just inside the closing body tag), and set the background image from there then it should load last, even for users with javascript disabled. Mike and claustrofob both make valid points.

Comment: Thanks! This works great, but it does lead to some tricky CSS positioning.